# php server side timer with several buttons to adjust the time

Tags: php, jquery, timer

I know this timer question have been asked several times but I think I have quite specific problem here which I can't find the answer. I'm trying to create an application where in the page there is a countdown timer with default value 0. and there is 3 buttons to reflect different tasks where each button will trigger the timer and start the countdown from 30 minutes when clicked. 
I have successfully made this with only 1 button by creating a database for storing timestamp on button click and run a function that calculating the elapsed time, and then I refresh the php every second using jquery. the php code is something like this

```
$button1 = $user->data->button1; // get button1 timestamp from database

// COUNTER is defined as 1800 seconds
$elapsed1 = COUNTER - (time() - $button1);
if ($elapsed1 < '0') {
    $elapsed1 = '0'; // stop timer so it doesn't go negative
    $disabled1 = ''; // make button1 enabled when timer stop
} else {
    $disabled1 = 'disabled'; // disabled button1 when timer running
}
$timer = $elapsed1;
```

now I want to add more buttons and add the same 30minutes for each button, so timer run 30minutes with 1 button clicked and 1hour with 2 buttons clicked. I was thinking to add more elapsed variable to the timer like

```
$timer = $elapsed1 + $elapsed2 + $elapsed3;
```

it still work perfectly with 1 button clicked, but it will be down by 2 seconds with 2 buttons clicked and down by 3 seconds with 3 buttons clicked. how can i achieve this?
any suggestion appreciated, or maybe there is a better practice for the code I made. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently it is possible the "down by 2 seconds" and "down by 3 seconds" incident is just latency from clicking the buttons and the timer countdown elapsing.

Also, instead of pinging your server every second, why not have the timestamp on start sent to the server, then wait (and count) using JavaScript/jQuery. After the timer runs out, contact the server to make sure it is legitimate. This would dramatically help with fan-out issues/server load.

If you follow this case, you will need the following restructure:

- JavaScript to handle initial post to server

  - Initial timestamp
  - Duration until action or end timestamp
- JavaScript to handle client-side timer

  - On Timer end -> use AJAX to contact the server, checking if necessary time has passed to do action, otherwise set a TimeOut to retry.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I understand that both down 2 and 3 seconds is because the timer are a sum of all elapsed time while each elapsed time are down by 1 second each. ideally when 1 button active the next button should go to the waiting list and start only when previous button end, but I don't know how to do that. and for the JavaScript, I'm trying to avoid JavaScript for timer cause I don't want user cheated by modified the source, that's why I use server side timer.

Comment: You could use your server to record the timestamp necessary for the events to take place.

Comment: sorry just saw your edited post about restructuring the code. I will examine and try it. thanks @Brandon White

Comment: If you feel my answer was at all helpful, please give it a +1. Thanks!